# Patterns in Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Consider an integer sequence
$$0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...$$

Each term denotes the number of times the corresponding natural number, starting from $0$, was hit by subsequent steps of sieving.

After we sieve the number $2$, the sequence becomes:

$$1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1...$$
We can easily see a pattern here: it's just $1, 0$ repeated ad infinitum.
The pattern's length is $2$.

After we sieve the number $3$, the sequence becomes:
$$2,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,1,1,1,0,2,0,1,1,1,0...$$

It's clear that we just repeat $2,0,1,1,1,0$, a pattern whose length is $6$.

So the pattern constantly expands until we get to the number $6$.
Here are the patterns for $5$ and $6$ respectively (I've omitted commas for tighter spacing):

$401121202120301220203110311120302111301130202210302120212110$
$501121302120401220303110411120402111401130302210402120312110$

Both patterns share the same length of $60$. It however expands for $7, 8, 9$ and again it doesn't for $10$.

Numerical evidence suggests that the pattern only ever expands after sieving **prime powers** - if $n = p^{e}$, the pattern's length for $n$ is the pattern's length for $n-1$ multiplied by $e$. So far I've validated this up to $18$.

Can this conjecture be proven?

**Most importantly,** is there a way to conceive this phenomenon intuitively?

[I've looked up](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C6%2C12%2C60%2C60%2C420%2C840%2C2520%2C2520%2C27720%2C27720%2C360360%2C360360%2C360360%2C720720%2C12252240%2C12252240&sort=&language=english&go=Search) the sequence of consecutive pattern lengths (starting from 2) and from what I can see it's got something to do with least common multiples.

Comment: You're right . The pattern will be always of length $lcm(1,2,\ldots,n)$ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is all about least common multiples.

First, note that what you're doing is adding sequences, termwise: for each $n$, let $S^n$ be the sequence with a $1$ in every $n$th spot, starting at the first, and $0$s elsewhere. E.g.

- $S^2=1,0,1,0, . . .$
- $S^5=1, 0,0,0,0, 1, 0,0,0,0, 1, 0,0,0,0, . . .$
- And so on.

Now, there's a natural way to add sequences: just add their corresponding terms. So, for instance, $S^2+S^5=2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, . . . $

You're asking about the period of $S^2+S^3+. . . +S^n$, as a function of $n$. Note the following (these are good exercises):

- If $A$, $B$ are periodic sequences with periods $a, b$ respectively, then $A+B$ has period $lcm(a, b)$. Similarly, if $C^1 , . . . , C^n$ have periods $c_1, . . . , c_n$ respectively, then $C^1+ . . . +C^n$ has period $lcm(c_1, . . . , c_n)$.
- $S^n$ has period $n$.
- If $n$ is not a prime power, then the lcm of $\{2, 3, . . . , n\}$ equals the lcm of $\{2, 3, . . . , n-1\}$, that is, the period doesn't change at non-prime-powers.
- Conversely, if $n$ *is* a prime power, then the lcm of $\{2, 3, . . . , n\}$ *does not* equal the lcm of $\{2, 3, . . . , n-1\}$.